# XmlSerializer constructor throws stack overflow exception when sent xsd.exe generated type

Tags: c#, xsd, xml-serialization, stack-overflow, xsd.exe

I have an xsd file that defines a configuration schema and I used **xsd.exe** to generate a class so I can use it to load configuration xml files. When I pass the type to the constructor of `XmlSerializer`, it throws a Stack Overflow exception. In my search for answers on this I found that this usually happens when there are recursive structures defined in the class, but this is not the case here (as far as I can see).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!-- Enumerations -->
<xs:simpleType name="HfEnvironments">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="DEV"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="QA_ST"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="PP_RT"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="PROD"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="RobotTypes">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="ANG"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="CAP"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="ENB"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="PLM"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="InstallOperations">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="File"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Package"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Query"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Task"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Folder"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="OperationModes">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Replace"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Remove"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="SuccessExpectancies">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Critical"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Important"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Negligible"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="BackupModes">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Always"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Never"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="Boolean">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="False"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="True"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="Installation">
    <xs:complexType>

        <xs:sequence>

            <xs:element name="Directives" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>

                        <xs:element name="Directive" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">

                                    <xs:element name="Operation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Type" type="tns:InstallOperations" use="required"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="ResourcePath" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="DestinationPath" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Success" type="tns:SuccessExpectancies" use="required"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="BackupMode" type="tns:BackupModes" use="optional"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="CreateDirectory" type="tns:Boolean" use="optional"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Mode" type="tns:OperationModes" use="optional"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>

                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="RobotType" type="tns:RobotTypes" use="required"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="Environment" type="tns:HfEnvironments" use="required"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="BackupRoot" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>

                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Here is the generated class:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.6.1055.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Installation {

    private InstallationDirective[] directivesField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Directive", IsNullable=false)]
    public InstallationDirective[] Directives {
        get {
            return this.directivesField;
        }
        set {
            this.directivesField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller")]
public partial class InstallationDirective {

    private InstallationDirectiveOperation[] operationField;

    private string nameField;

    private RobotTypes robotTypeField;

    private HfEnvironments environmentField;

    private string backupRootField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Operation")]
    public InstallationDirectiveOperation[] Operation {
        get {
            return this.operationField;
        }
        set {
            this.operationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public RobotTypes RobotType {
        get {
            return this.robotTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.robotTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public HfEnvironments Environment {
        get {
            return this.environmentField;
        }
        set {
            this.environmentField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="anyURI")]
    public string BackupRoot {
        get {
            return this.backupRootField;
        }
        set {
            this.backupRootField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller")]
public partial class InstallationDirectiveOperation {

    private InstallOperations typeField;

    private string resourcePathField;

    private string destinationPathField;

    private SuccessExpectancies successField;

    private BackupModes backupModeField;

    private bool backupModeFieldSpecified;

    private Boolean createDirectoryField;

    private bool createDirectoryFieldSpecified;

    private OperationModes modeField;

    private bool modeFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public InstallOperations Type {
        get {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ResourcePath {
        get {
            return this.resourcePathField;
        }
        set {
            this.resourcePathField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="anyURI")]
    public string DestinationPath {
        get {
            return this.destinationPathField;
        }
        set {
            this.destinationPathField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public SuccessExpectancies Success {
        get {
            return this.successField;
        }
        set {
            this.successField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public BackupModes BackupMode {
        get {
            return this.backupModeField;
        }
        set {
            this.backupModeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool BackupModeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.backupModeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.backupModeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public Boolean CreateDirectory {
        get {
            return this.createDirectoryField;
        }
        set {
            this.createDirectoryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool CreateDirectorySpecified {
        get {
            return this.createDirectoryFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.createDirectoryFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public OperationModes Mode {
        get {
            return this.modeField;
        }
        set {
            this.modeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool ModeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.modeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.modeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller")]
public enum InstallOperations {

    /// <remarks/>
    File,

    /// <remarks/>
    Package,

    /// <remarks/>
    Task,

    /// <remarks/>
    Folder,
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller")]
public enum SuccessExpectancies {

    /// <remarks/>
    Critical,

    /// <remarks/>
    Important,

    /// <remarks/>
    Negligible,
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller")]
public enum BackupModes {

    /// <remarks/>
    Always,

    /// <remarks/>
    Never,
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller")]
public enum Boolean {

    /// <remarks/>
    False,

    /// <remarks/>
    True,
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller")]
public enum OperationModes {

    /// <remarks/>
    Replace,

    /// <remarks/>
    Remove,
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller")]
public enum RobotTypes {

    /// <remarks/>
    ANG,

    /// <remarks/>
    CAP,

    /// <remarks/>
    ENB,

    /// <remarks/>
    PLM,
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/RobotInstaller")]
public enum HfEnvironments {

    /// <remarks/>
    DEV,

    /// <remarks/>
    QA_ST,

    /// <remarks/>
    PP_RT,

    /// <remarks/>
    PROD,
}
```

Here's the code that throws the exception:

```
private Installation LoadInstallationDefinition(string resourcePath)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourcePath)) { throw new ArgumentException("The value cannot be null or white space.", nameof(resourcePath)); }

            Installation result = null;

            using (var installationFile = LoadEmbeddedFile(resourcePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Installation));
                    result = (Installation)serializer.Deserialize(installationFile);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    var message = exception.Message;
                    throw;
                }
            };

            return result;
        }
```

The exception occurs on the XmlSerializer constructor, not when the XML is loaded, so there is some problem reflecting the type. But the exception itself gives me no more information than:

> System.StackOverflowException was unhandled   HResult=-2147023895
>   Message=Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown. 
>   InnerException:

Comment: As I specified, the error doesn't happen on deserialization of the XML file but in the constructor of the XmlSerializer that is given the type. The code for the type is included.

Comment: I've figured out a hint - but still not an answer. In my Program.Main() function I am subscribing to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event. If I create the Serializer before the subscription, it works, but not when it's created after the subscription. I've tried this out immediately before and after the subscription code line. I don't understand why that would be because the 'Installation' type does not depend on any external assemblies.